# Cloth Physics hung on pole?

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I am trying to render a physics cloth of a flag. But I don't want to pin it to two points/an edge... I  want it to be wrapped around the pole. In reference to the image I have uploaded: The fabric is to be folded over near one side and stitched to itself about 2" in along the edge and one top edge. This would allow a dowel to fit into the "sleeve". How can I do this in blender so that I can render it on a pole? I tried to but it doesn't work properly.

I made the dowel an AddPassive in Rigid Body Tools and the flag a Cloth in Physics. They don't intersect.

I also would like to know how I can better make the sleeve rather than making a tube.

Thanks!

[image: image1]
[image: image2]
[image: image3]

Comment: I would use *collision* instead of rigid body for the dowel.

Comment: Is the sleeve open on the bottom?  I would also recommend deleting the top face of the sleeve, selecting the edge loop around where it was, and doing a *grid fill*.  To do a grid fill hit [space] and type “grid fill”, you can then hit [F6] and adjust the rotation to get nice even quads.

Comment: The sleeve is open on the bottom.

Comment: I tried using collision and it still explodes into itself

Answer (score 3):

I don't think subdivision and self-collision matters much, even the model size (just don't make them extremely tiny). In fact, subdivision generates even worse artifacts in some cases.

For the "exploding" issue, what matters much is the **Distance** parameter in *Cloth Collision* panel for cloth object, and the **Outer** parameter in *Collision* panel for the collision object. When the initial gap between the two objects are relatively small, you need to tweak these two parameters specifically so that they will not become "procedually intersecting" before running simulation.

Of course, subdivision will lead to much better result, as long as key parameters like above can be taken good care of. But it doesn't mean other things are trivial. For example, **don't forget to apply Scale for object** when doing so.

[image]

**[Example File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ojv5B6Lb-3b3ptejJkMWZKYzg/view?usp=sharing)**

Answer (score 0):

You need more subdivisions on the part that goes over the pole. add a subdivide modifier or give more in edit mode.

Comment: I've determined that the reason my model is "exploding" is because of the Cloth self collision. When I turn it off it works properly. But I need the cloth self collision on. What do I do?

Comment: Have you added more subdivisions?

Comment: Yes, many subdivisions and with different designs

Comment: @Peter The cloth simulator cannot deal with small models very well, try scaling the objects much larger.